# Errors installing nodegit in linux

Tags: nodegit

I entered `npm install nodegit` and got the following error

```
npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/bin/npm" "install" "nodegit"
npm ERR! node v6.9.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! path /opt/portal_server/node_modules/nodegit
npm ERR! code EISGIT

npm ERR! git /opt/portal_server/node_modules/nodegit: Appears to be a git repo or submodule.
npm ERR! git     /opt/portal_server/node_modules/nodegit
npm ERR! git Refusing to remove it. Update manually,
npm ERR! git or move it out of the way first.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /opt/portal_server/npm-debug.log
```

Could you please suggest a way to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

Try running this

```sh
sudo rm -rf node_modules/*/.git/
```

Then try installing `nodegit`